# How do I specify ARGB format textures in my input declaration?

Tags: directx11

```
    const D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC InputLayoutDesc::Basic32[3] = 
{
    {"POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
    {"NORMAL",   0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
    {"TEXCOORD", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 24, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0}
};
```

The TEXCOORD,
There is no support for a image that is ARGB. Only DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT

How can I load ARBG?

Or can I convert a ARGB TO A RGBA IMAGE?

Answer (score 1):

> The TEXCOORD, There is no support for a image that is ARGB. Only
>   DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT

What you are defining here is the *vertex input layout*; this has nothing to do with the format of the textures you will eventually use, and instead everything to do with the format of the texture coordinates used in the vertex data. Generally these are 2D, so you'd only need `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT`. `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT` would be used if you needed 4D texture coordinates, which you probably don't.

Perhaps the use of the `R` and `G` in the format enumeration is just confusing you; in this case the 'name' of those channels is irrelevant, it's the width of those channels (32-bit) and amount (R and G == 2D, R, G, B and A == 4D) that matter.

You can load ARGB textures when you actually load the texture data from the disk.

Answer (score 0):

This looks unusual. Texture coordinates only requires 2 component X and Y, thus you can use DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT or DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16_FLOAT or any other 2 component format. And for texture coordinates, normally you wouldn't store it in an image file anyway.

If you insist on using ARGB data, either you can convert it offline, simply by reading 4 32-bit values at a time, swap their position and write out to a file, or alternatively just read your data as is, and in vertex or pixel shader you can interpret first component as A, second as R and so on. Remember DXGI format is just a convention, your shader has the freedom to interpret data in anyway it wishes to.

By the way, I would suggest reducing floating point accuracy. Instead of using 32 bits per component, you can use 16 bits and most of the time it is pretty good, and you get 50% size reduction. 8 bit normalized can be used for texture coordinates if you know your data will not go out of the [0,1] range, for further reduction.

Comment: Ok, I see now. appreciate the help!

Answer (score -1):

You the data for Normals and TextChords in the each others place, Try switching them like mine below:

```
static D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC VertexLayout [ ] =
{
        {"POSITION",0,DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,0,0,D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA,0}
        {"NORMAL",0,DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT,D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA,0}
        {"TEXTCOORD",0,DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT,0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT,D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA,0}
}
```